# I need to delete the "li" who has the class Equal to the attr input

Tags: jquery

this is my code jquery

remove the li when checkbox is unchecked

someone can help me please...

```
$('.field').on({
    'click': function() {
        var price = $(this).val();
        text = $(this).next().html();
        name = $(this).attr("name");
                  
        if($(this).is(':checked')) { 
            $('.content-car ul').append('<li class='+ name + '><span class="titre">'+ text +'</span><span class="prix">'+ price + '</span></li>');
        } else {
            //
        } 
    }
});
```

Comment: does the `.content-car ul` element have more then one li element inside?

Comment: thx but i still have the same problem ...

Comment: *still have the same problem* - what problem?

Comment: the checkbox is unchecked and th li item still exist !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$('.content-car ul li.' + name).remove();` to remove `li`.

Try it below.

```js
$('.field').on({
  'click': function() {
  
    var price = $(this).val();
    text = $(this).next().html();
    name = $(this).attr("name");

    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $('.content-car ul').append('<li class=' + name + '><span class="titre">' + text + '</span><span class="prix">' + price + '</span></li>');
    } else {
      $('.content-car ul li.' + name).remove();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='content-car'>
  <ul>
    <li>---</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div>
  <input type='checkbox' value='1' name='1' class='field' />
  <label>1</label>
  <input type='checkbox' value='2' name='2' class='field' />
  <label>2</label>
</div>
```